# Бот отмечает участников в группе. Telebot, python 3.8

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, sqlite3

Помогите пожалуйста новичку) Как сделать так, что бы бот отмечал участников в группе, базу данных через sqlite3 я подключил, вдруг понадобится. Python 3.8 , Telebot

Comment: если нужно уточнить, пишите сразу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавь `@` к нику юзера

```py
import telebot 
import time
bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")   

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    nick = message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"@{nick}")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Оо, спасибо, второй раз помогаете)

Comment: Я отвечаю на вопросы только в этой нише, так-что не последний раз увидимся)

Comment: ахах, я сегодня еще один вопрос задам) ждите

Comment: Ожидаю, отвечу на всё!